# React navigation bottom tabs not showing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have a simple App.js that renders 3 screens Login.js Register.js and Index.js when the user is logged in he should see the a screen with two tabs, the tabs are not showing.

App.js

```
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <NativeBaseProvider>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Index" component={Index} />

          <Stack.Screen
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
            name="Login"
            component={Login}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Register"
            component={Register}
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NativeBaseProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Index.js

```
const Index = () => {
  
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

  
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Home",
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profil"
        component={Profil}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Profil",
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

Home and Profile are simple components that returns text, Home.js gets rendered first but the bottom navigation bar doesn't show.

Comment: Take a look at Authentication flows: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change code like this:

```
export const AppNavigation = () => {
  //If isLoggedIn you will render tabs, in other wath render auth flow
  const isLoggedIn = false;
  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {isLoggedIn ? <AuthNavigation /> : <MainNavigation />}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
};

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const AuthNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
        name="Login"
        component={Login}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Register"
        component={Register}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const MainNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Home",
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={Profile}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Profile",
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```